# NodeLocalDns on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am trying to implement nodeLocalDns on my eks cluster.
I have deployed the master branch of https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/nodelocaldns/

I need help with a few things here

1. The kubernetes official doc says that - If using kube-proxy in IPVS mode, --cluster-dns flag to kubelet needs to be modified to use  that NodeLocal DNSCache is listening on. Otherwise, there is no need to modify the value of the --cluster-dns flag, since NodeLocal DNSCache listens on both the kube-dns service IP as well as .

How can I find out in EKS ,which mode is my kube-proxy  runnning on?

2. How can I verify if the DNS requests are going to nodeLocalDns ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find which mode kube-proxy is running in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66746018/how-to-find-which-mode-kube-proxy-is-running-in)

Comment: https://support.tools/post/deploy-eks-with-nodelocaldns/ and https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/dns/nodelocaldns might be worth checking out